# Communication issue of ACR122u NFC Card Reader with android phone in P2P mode?

Tags: android

I am sending following TgInitAsTarget command :FF0000002DD48C0100000000004001FE0FBBBAA6C9890000000000000000FFFF01FE0FBBBAA6C98900000646666D01011000

to ACR122u to configure it in Target mode for P2P communication with android phone.

In case of Nexus S command runs successfully.But in case of Samsung Galaxy SII error code returned (6300). Which means "Operation Failed". I am not able to find why this is returned.
Please help me on this. Thank a lot.

Comment: when I hear about Samsung...I "facepalm" all the time

Answer (score 0):

Same problem is here,ACR122 is not communicating with SGII Android_2.3.4. I guess on this device NFC-P2P mode is not implemented.
Whats OS version of your SGII, Is there any other data you are getting on response?